# if else to test legal drinking age

Tags: java

Is the following code incorrect for the following question?

> Write an if statement to test if an int variable age is equal to 21, the legal drinking age.

The answer I typed is as follows:

```
if(age = 21) 
{
   System.out.print("Legal Drinking age");
}
```

Comment: as an experiment, try turning that first line around. if(21 = age). See what happens

Comment: You need to write `ìf(age == 21)` the single `=` is used for assignments

Comment: *"Is the following code incorrect for the following question?"* Yes, it is incorrect. Did you bother to try it? (Hint: It won't compile.) (@Gimby: It fails to compile either way, in Java. `age` would have to be `boolean` for the Yoda condition to matter.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder argh, true; not all tricks from the days of C-programming translate to Java in all situations. In my own defense: the main purpose was to tickle a certain someone to actually go compile the code for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
if (age == 21) {
   System.out.print("Legal Drinking age");
}
```

`=` is used for assignments

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if(age == 21) 
{
   System.out.print("Legal Drinking age");
}
```

You are assigning the value 21 to `age` variable not comparing.

```
age = 21 //Assignment
```